# Skipping viduy of tachanun

Tags: halacha, minhag, tachanun

I have found some people who have a minhag to skip the viduy and continue with vehu rachum instead. I have heard a halakha that says you're allowed to do so *bediavad*. Is there any posek who agrees with this minhag?

Comment: Ashkenazi Minhag begins with vehurachum

Comment: I would like to know what detail is missing?

Comment: Nusach Ashkenaz has the main bit of tachanun after Vehu Rachum, specifically the paragraph of "haPoteach Yad" rather than before

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt, your edit makes sense, but are you sure that was the OP's intention? Remember, the Sephardim say vehu rachum after the whole main part of tachanun (after veanachnu lo neida) and after some short selichos, not just after the viduy and nefilas apaim like the Chasidim.